# C++ std::shared_ptr usage and information

Tags: c++, g++, shared-ptr

I am trying to use `std::shared_ptr` in my code. I have seen there have been other questions on the subject, but I am still getting a compiler error. Have I got the right version of gcc and setup?

What I have done:

I have tried to compile my code with both headers separately — `<memory>` and `<tr1/memory>` but still get the errors below in both cases.

The version of gcc I am using is

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.3.2
```

When I include `<memory>` header I use `std::shared_ptr` and with the `<tr1/memory>` header I use `std::tr1::shared_ptr`? Is this correct?

I have set up the shared_ptr as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<A*> ptr_A = shared_ptr( new A() );
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
src/WH.cxx:156: error: 'shared_ptr' is not a member of 'std'
src/WH.cxx:162: error: 'shared_ptr' was not declared in this scope
```

when I try the `<tr1/memory>` header

```
src/WH.cxx:156: error: 'std::tr1' has not been declared
src/WH.cxx:162: error: 'shared_ptr' was not declared in this scope
```

Looks like I am not including something correctly. Any ideas?

I know the boost library has `shared_ptr` but these libraries are not an option for me at the moment.

**EDIT:
Just to add, my compiler options are as follows:
g++  -O3 -g3 -m32 -fPIC  -Wno-deprecated -pthread -m32
Am I missing anything?**

P.S. Is there any useful literature on the std smart pointers?

Comment: You'd expect the documentation to include two things, but it doesn't: which header file to include, and which version of gcc first introduced it. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/shared_ptr.html

Comment: Depending on your version of GCC, `std::shared_ptr` may not exist, or may require you to specify `-std=c++0x` as a compiler option.

Comment: First, gcc 4.3 is very old. As of when you wrote your question, gcc 4.6 is out. Second, I believe shared_ptr is a C++11 feature, so even once you have the correct version, you will probably need to use -std=c++0x to use it.

Comment: Requests for tutorials/literature is outside the scope of this site as defined in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @wjl Some of us can't update compilers easily.  Embedded systems often come in a collection of things, including compilers and hardware packages.  Updating compiler versions can require physically changing the hardware, and that can be _very_ expensive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`std::tr1::shared_ptr` is part of the TR1 additions to the C++ STL.
With GCC, it is available either through `#include <tr1/memory>` (GCC 4.1) or `#include <memory>` (GCC 4.3)

Comment: In GCC it depends on the presence of the `-std=c++0x` compiler option, too. (Or `-std=c++11` from 4.7 onwards.)

Comment: Okay so here is my compiler options I am using. g++  -O3 -g3 -m32 -fPIC  -Wno-deprecated -pthread -m32  .  do I need to add -std=c++0x

Comment: `-std=c++0x` isn't needed for `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, is it?

Comment: Looks Like it is needed Fred. Well for my set up. Thanks Again!

Comment: With C++11 it is now `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 10):

You were also asking for references or literature...

I found 3 articles that may help:

- [An article on Smart Pointers](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html), which is an overview good for a general understanding.
- [An actual reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for `std::shared_ptr`.
- [A great tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15361__1/A-TR1-Tutorial-Smart-Pointers.htm) discussing every method of TR1 `shared_ptr` along with sample code.

Also a comment on your code example:

```
std::shared_ptr<A*> ptr_A = shared_ptr( new A() );
```

The template argument should be A instead of A* :

```
std::shared_ptr<A> ptr_A = shared_ptr( new A() );
```

Comment: Good references, even though technically that is not [what this site is for](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: true, although he was clever enough to ask at least one stackoverflow adequate question. And honestly, when i see references from well reputated people, I usually follow and have a look - and this helps  alot in the long run. cheers and merry Xmas

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have `shared_ptr` in std you can use it from boost.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_A( new A() );
```

Comment: Should be `shared_ptr`, not `shred_ptr`. (I know -- the error is in the question too.)

Comment: sorry :) was a bit quick here. Wanted to just point out that there shouldn't be any A* in the template.

Comment: @murrekatt: The OP has said "I know the boost library has shared_ptr but these libraries are not an option for me at the moment :-(".

Comment: Shouldn't it be boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_A( new A ); (no parents after A)?