# Custom GCC 4.8.2 on RHEL6 gives build error with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, rhel6, gcc4.8

I am using CMake 2.8.11 and GCC 4.8.2. I was building some C++ code which used `std::shared_ptr` which built fine in MS VS 2012 but when I tried the same on RHEL6 using GCC 4.8.2, I promptly ran into the following error:

```
error: 'shared_ptr' is not a member of 'std'
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171444/c-stdshared-ptr-usage-and-information) question with responses that I thought addressed and I promptly added `-std=c++11` to my `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, but I still keep running into the error. I add the flag in CMake simply using:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" CACHE STRING "Add C++ 11 flags")
```

I set my custom compiler in CMake using:

```
SET(GCC_DIR "</path/to/custom>/gcc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${GCC_DIR}/bin/g++ CACHE FILEPATH "CXX compiler")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${GCC_DIR}/bin/gcc CACHE FILEPATH "C compiler")
```

The include is

```
#include <memory>
```

which in turn has

```
#include <bits/shared_ptr.h>
```

which defines the `shared_ptr` class. So I'm not sure why I keep getting the error (and yes I cleared cached and rebuilt after adding the `-std=c++11` compiler option). Any ideas are very much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

I created a simple program (main.cpp) as follows:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<int> pint = std::make_shared<int>();
  std::cout << "Pint points to " << pint.get() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Then I built it using `<path/to/custom/>g++ main.cpp -o prog` and promptly ran into the same error (above). Next I did: `<path/to/custom/>g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o prog` and it compiles & runs OK. For my real application, I added the `-std=c++11` flag to linker flags as well (in addition to compiler flags) in my `CMake` config system, but I still see the same error. Proceeding to check the `CMakeCache` to see if the flags are property registered, but any ideas are appreciated.

**EDIT 2:**

Suprisingly, I found in `CMakeCache` that the `-std=c++11` flag is not being added to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, etc. So this must have to do with the error. I am trying to fix it so that it actually takes this flag. Thanks all.

Comment: Try with -std=c++0x. It might work as some compilers use this instead of -std=c++11.

Comment: I tried that first actually, and it didn't work. But the link I referred to mentioned to use c++11 for GCC > 4.7, and so I did, but even that didn't work.

Comment: RHEL6 ships with a much older gcc, are you sure you're actually invoking gcc 4.8.2 and that it's properly installed ?

Comment: Let us see the cmakelists.txt too.

Comment: @nos: That's a good point. Yes, I am invoking GCC 4.8.2, that's for sure. The whole application is built with a custom GCC 4.8.2 compiler installed on RH6. I did not do the installation of the compiler. Do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo It seems to be. Can you at least verify that you're invoking this custom installed gcc, and not the default gcc v 4.4 ?

Comment: @nos: Yes, see my edited comment.

Comment: Your include path is for gcc 4.4 but you using gcc 4.8.2. I highly recommend to use devtools-2 on CentOS 6/RHEL 6.
   wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo &&
    yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils devtoolset-2-gcc-c++ &&
    scl enable devtoolset-2 bash

Comment: Then you can try to narrow it down. Create a single example.cpp file that uses std::shared_ptr , , compile it by hand by running `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 example.cpp` , run g++ -v to view its version. If that doesn't work, there's a problem with your gcc installation, if it does work, it's a problem with your build system.

Comment: @nos: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea. What did you mean by run g++ -v to view the version though? If ran it with the g++ from the custom compiler, I know I would see 4.8.2, so that remark seemed out of place. Wouldn't just compiling the example program with the custom compiler suffice?

Comment: Run `g++ -v`, and it prints version information.

Comment: @avesus: I've instructed CMake the path to my custom GCC dir and compilers; so I am including the correct headers at the intended include path assuming CMake does what it is supposed to.

Comment: No, that remark is not out of place. If somone has installed a custom g++, they hopefully did so in a way that would not conflict with the normal gcc installation of RHEL. That means somehow your PATH must be changed for you to invoke g++ and get gcc 4.8.2, and if you somehow are in a shell that don't have this altered PATH, or there's things in your cmake files messing with the PATH, your assumptions could be wrong when compiling the suggested example.cpp. Ofcourse this was before we knew you already set the proper PATH, since all you told us was you ran g++. Stil, always verify assumptions.

Comment: @nos: I added some more notes on how this is done in CMake. But I still don't see the value of running `g++ -v`; if I did just that, then yeah I would see 4.4.7 or whatever comes default with RHEL6; but our environment is set up to use GCC 4.8.2 to build the application (again, see the snippet above). So I don't see what running `g++ -v` would tell me that I don't already know. But yeah, compiling the small test program is helpful.

Comment: You're free to skip running it, it was just a suggestion so you are actually sure about what's going on.  albeit I cannot see why you would, it'll take a second at most. But please, create a simple example and run g++ by hand so you can verify if it's the compiler or cmake at fault.

Comment: I highly recommend to run shell with `scl enable devtoolset-2 bash`. It sets `PATH` appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer confirms the hunch in **EDIT 2** of my question. Apparently `CMake 2.8.x` is not appending to the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` using the `SET` command using the syntax shown in my question (as per the documentation); I tried other variants of the `SET` command to append, to no avail.

So finally, instead of appending, I assigned separately for the case when C++11 is to be enabled and when it is to be disabled, as follows:

```
IF(USE_C++11)
...
ELSE(USE_C++11)
...
ENDIF(USE_C++11)
```

This worked fine. Thanks to @nos for the idea to make an isolated example.